# XMPP 0059/0313 Archive message - paging backwards through result set

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, strophe, strophe.js

I have gotten the last 10 messages from archive, and trying to get the 10 before that on request and so on.

On the XMPP doc. it said i set the before with my UID??

http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0059.html#backwards

```
<iq type='set' from='stpeter@jabber.org/roundabout' to='users.jabber.org' id='back1'>
  <query xmlns='jabber:iq:search'>
    <nick>Pete</nick>
    <set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>
      <max>10</max>
      <before>peter@pixyland.org</before>
    </set>
  </query>
</iq>
```

or this?? http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html#query-paging

with some ID in the after tag? I am very confused, can anyone give me some pointer, thanks!

```
<iq type='set' id='q29303'>
  <query xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:1'>
      <x xmlns='jabber:x:data' type='submit'>
        <field var='FORM_TYPE' type='hidden'><value>urn:xmpp:mam:1</value></field>>
        <field var='start'><value>2010-08-07T00:00:00Z</value></field>
      </x>
      <set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>
         <max>10</max>
         <after>09af3-cc343-b409f</after>
      </set>
  </query>
</iq>
```

I tried putting in before with my UID and it didnt work `<before>peter@server.org</before>`

ANd i have an error `<error code='400' type='modify'><bad-request xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/></error></iq></body>`

I am using strophe.js mam plugin and rsm plugin

Answer (score 3):

When you receive first page limited by RSM with `max`=10, you will receive `first` and `last` UIDs:

```
<iq type='result' id='q29302'>
  <fin xmlns='urn:xmpp:mam:1'>
    <set xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/rsm'>
      <first index='0'>28482-98726-73623</first>
      <last>09af3-cc343-b409f</last>
      <count>10</count>
    </set>
  </fin>
</iq>
```

These are UIDs of **messages**, which you can use in `before` and `after` subsequent queries.

Comment: I am kind of getting it to work, but it is returning the results backwards.... and i am not getting a UID for the message but the count, so i am just putting those counts into the before and after.....not sure how to flip it backwards tho

Comment: Hi there @unor , i got an issue , i have messages 300 in a group ,  but the last UID which stream sending is not the value that i mentioned above. the value was like 100 or 130. when i tried to archive messages with <before> tag, i'm unable to get messages.
when i use after tag, i'm getting messages from First. like starting from 1st message.not before last message.
Please help me in this issue.

Comment: @SureshMopidevi: It’s not my answer :) -- Anyway, if vitalyster’s answer didn’t help in your case, and if your case is not exactly the same as John’s, I would suggest that you create a new question for this.

Comment: Okay, i will @unor.